# Page Not Found -- No mapping for /GET

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockmvc

I am trying to write test for my controller for my SPRING-BOOT CRUD operation project using junit5 and mocking. While running the test it is showing below error. Not able to understand what is the problem.

Error:-

```
10:24:51.840 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet -- Initializing Servlet ''
10:24:51.842 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet -- Completed initialization in 1 ms
10:24:51.865 [main] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound -- No mapping for GET /content

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.duration"
```

ContentController file:-

```
package com.example.sixth.controller;


import com.example.sixth.entity.Content;
import com.example.sixth.service.ContentService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
public class ContentController {



    private final ContentService contentService;

    public ContentController(ContentService contentService) {
        this.contentService = contentService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/content")
    public List<Content> show(){
        return contentService.showAll();
    }


    @PostMapping("/content")
    public String save(@RequestBody Content content){
        return contentService.save(content);
    }


    @GetMapping("/content/title/{param}")
    public List<Content> getContentStartWith(@PathVariable("param") String title){
        return contentService.getContentStartWith(title);
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/content/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id){
        return contentService.delete(id);
    }


    @GetMapping("/id")
    public List<Content>getById(@RequestParam Integer minId,
                                @RequestParam Integer maxId){
        return contentService.getById(minId,maxId);
    }


    @GetMapping("/content/{id}")
    public Optional<Content> findById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        return contentService.findById(id);
    }

}
```

TestFile:-

```
package com.example.sixth;

import com.example.sixth.controller.ContentController;
import com.example.sixth.entity.Content;
import com.example.sixth.service.ContentService;
import com.example.sixth.service.ContentServiceImpl;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvcBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
//import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;


@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@SpringBootTest
public class ContentControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    ContentService mockService;

    @InjectMocks
    ContentController contentController;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.mockMvc= MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(mockService).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testfindall() throws Exception {
        Content content = (Content.builder()
                .id(3)
                .title("SECOND!!")
                .duration(38)
                .location("Bangalore").build());
        List<Content> contentList = new ArrayList<>();
        contentList.add(content);
        Mockito.when(mockService.showAll()).thenReturn(contentList);
        
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/content").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.duration",is(content.getDuration())));
//        List<Content> actual=contentController.show();
//        System.out.println(actual.get(0).toString());
//        assertEquals(actual,contentList);

    }
```

Btw when using assert it is working but with mockMvc it is showing error ..

Comment: Try adding the following annotation on the Test class: `@WebMvcTest(ContentController.class)`

Comment: Got this error 

`Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.sixth.controller.ContentController required a bean of type 'com.example.sixth.service.ContentService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.sixth.service.ContentService' in your configuration.`

Comment: Change `@Mock` to `@MockBean` on the `ContentService` field in the test class.

Comment: Still Page not found : No mapping for GET /content error is there.

Comment: Try removing `contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` in the request part.

Comment: No...Didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254490/discussion-between-harsh-agarwal-and-yousaf).

Comment: On top of @Yousaf’s advice, also remove entire BeforeEach method.

Comment: Thanks @Lesiak ..the mapping worked ...but still an error is showing..can u please guide me through that.. Error is:-

`java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.duration"`



`Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['duration'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.`

Comment: Your assertion is wrong. You return an array of objects, not an object.

Comment: Thanks @Lesiak for pointing that out...I tried searching how to assert with array of objects but couldn't find one.. Could you please tell me what exact changes to be made in 
`  "$",is(contentList) ` 
code. 
TIA.

Comment: I'd try "$[*]" to get entire list or "$[0]" to get first element. Check which approach produces more readable errors.

Comment: It worked Thanks.. @Lesiak
Can u pls tell me why removing before Each method was necessary ..like it just initializes the mockMvc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, you are trying to write a unit test for a single controller.

@WebMvcTest is the right tool for the job.

1. annotate your test with @WebMvcTest(Content controller.class)
   It will create spring context with web slice of the app.
2. You need to provide missing beans so that spring can create the instance of your controller. These are provided with @MockBean, not @Mock
3. Get requests do not have a body in http1 and http2. Remove content type in your request.
4. Lastly, you have MockMvc instance provided by WebMvcTest (this annotation is annotated with @AutoConfigureWebMvc), injected to your test with @Autowired. You were overwriting this instance with another, badly cofigured one in @BeforeEach. On top of that, you were also overwriting mocks. This is why entire BeforeEach needed to be deleted.

See [Unit Testing With @WebMvcTest](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#unit-testing-with-webmvctest)